# Ideas & Suggestions for AJAX/Flash Streaming Radio

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, audio-streaming, internet-radio

I had the idea to make something similar to google music (before their idea was public) but instead of just letting the user play the music they could also "publish" it and stream it. Then they could link their friends to their channel.

I was wanting the interface to be ran by JQuery and very basic. Allow for uploading of their music and then they can create a "to be played list" where the backend radio streamer plays right from the list. It should be noted the streaming upload is actually from my server, and not their comp (unless this is doable?) They could also record their voice over/sound effects from a flash "record" button that would just record their voice via mic on flash, make a mp3 file and add it to the "to be played" list.

So my question is this, what's the best way to accomplish this? Are there already similar open source JQuery projects that I could go from? What streaming back-end radio streamer is the best?

The last one I checked out was icecast and their was a specific version (not official) I had to get that would let me do both ogg and mp3, because normally the versions did one or the other. How would I give it ability to stop/skip to the next song and simulate that streaming live. Change up a internal playlist and send some sort of linux signal?

PS: things to note. I have average experience with javascript/Jquery. Limited with flash. above average with PHP. I have my own dedicated linux server so any open-source, freeware or relative cheap software is an option.

Comment: I think there may be some legal issues with storing the music on your server and streaming it to the user's client.  I think the best route would be to look into some sort of P2P with flash.

Comment: For streaming server you can check red5 that has lots of cool feature but based on java, you can not only play streams, also record. it saves the files in flv format that you can easily convert into mp3 using ffmpeg. might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the jquery plugin called jplayer http://jplayer.org/ for a streaming music player and it worked really well - I would definitely recommend it.  One cool thing is that if it's opened in a browser that doesn't support html5, it defaults back to flash.

Also, it's open source, so if you need more / different functionality you could always look at the source and build on it or get inspiration from it.

Answer (score 0):

I had an Internet Radio startup a few years back... The economy/lack of funding/lack of interest funded it.  We had a couple of demo stations running through ice cast and it worked very well for us. We used a front end solution we wrote in Flash/Actionscript for scheduling the music and breaks.

I think you're skill set is probably adequate to create the front end that you describe.  I will tell you that you will likely find the Sound model in as accessed through JS/jQuery limiting and may want to consider Flash at this point... Even HTML5's audio tag cannot access meta data in the music file, or give you the ability to have users adjust the pan.

Flash has a very rich set of sound classes that you may benefit from.

Sounds like a fun project! Good luck!